# Software Licensing in Hostile/Sensitive Environment

Tags: security

One of my clients needs to deploy his software in a knowingly licensing-hostile, piracy-friendly country, in the Defense field.

Tracking authorized & legit software usage through the network will be complicated to negotiate with his client, as the software will probably run in a confined environment.

I am thinking of possible workarounds for this. I have a few Tracks/Ideas, like asynchronous dumps and regular monthly license rechecks. Any ideas/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

We were using a hardware + software solution from Wibu. While we used [WibuKey](http://www.wibu.com/us/wibukey.html), the proper solution would probably be [Codemeter](http://www.wibu.com/us/order-form-for-codemeter-software-development-kit.html).

Codemeter comes with an SDK that you can integrate into your application. <sup>This is the software recommendation part.</sup>

Be aware that there are USB-to-Ethernet boxes that could be used to share a dongle between users. However, it's possible to query in code whether the dongle is attached locally (we forgot that part initially).

Pro: strongest security possible IMHO

Contra: hardware cost and hardware shipping / exchange in case of loss.

While it's basically simple to integrate, make sure you read the developer's manual. It has a lot of good content. This may take some days to understand and implement.